# Strange screens in iPhone5s 7.1 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have xcode 6 and target is 7.0.I am having no problem with other simulators.But in iPhone5s7.1 the screen has black top bar and bottom bar[image]

Comment: Try adding Default-568h@2x.png (640 × 1136 pixels) and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use @2x.png files by default, then I'm sure that your app will look good on iPhone5s and other retina devices.

as @WonderMonster answer you will have to make @2x size images 
Read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconM[atrix.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the iPhone 5s has a taller screen than the iPhone 4 and earlier.  Most likely you are setting your view to a static size rather than setting it to dynamically resize.